# How to update URL route after completing a search query in Asp.net core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to update my URL route after a search action within my controller is completed using Asp.net core MVC.

Once I find the specific database object, I return the obj model into a View, but once the view is displayed with the correct Model information, the URL route/address does not change.

It remains as https://localhost:7236/Ingredient/Search

It should be more like: https://localhost:7236/Ingredient/Search?q{ingredient-name}/{id}

I am learning C# / .Net and trying to understand how things work. Pardon my lack of proper syntax/grammar when trying to describe my process.

**Search Form Page**

```
    <form asp-controller="Ingredient" asp-action="Search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input class="search-input form-control" name="search" placeholder="Ingredient..." />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            <a asp-controller="Ingredient" asp-action="List" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View List</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Search Form Action in Controller**

```
            // SEARCH --> HOMEPAGE
        // Search by title and return details page of the ingredient if correct
        public IActionResult Search(string search, Ingredient obj)
        {
            var getResult = from ingredient in _db.ingredients where ingredient.Name == search select ingredient;
            if(getResult.Count() > 0)
            {
                var result = getResult.FirstOrDefault();
                obj = result;
                return View("Info", obj);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: A URL can contain parameters after the question mark like in this case you want to add a parameter.  Parameters in the URL must have a key followed by an equal sign and multiple parameters are separated by an ampersand.  Parameters can also be passed by add a HTTP Header to the request.   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search"/>
```

to replace

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
```

And since you only have a input named `search` in the form,the url will be like

```
https://localhost:7236/Ingredient/Search?search={...}
```

result:

[image]